# how to resize img for machine learning model

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

i want to resize my image into `(1, 28, 28)`

my code is here

```
from keras.preprocessing.image import load_img
from keras.preprocessing import image

img1 = image.load_img(path=path,grayscale=True,target_size=(28,28))
img1 = image.img_to_array(img1)

print(img1.shape)
## (28, 28, 1)
```

if `target_size=(1,28,28)` then it gives me `(1, 28, 1)`

i don't know why it give me this kind of output

how can i do that?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: @Nakor does `numpy.swapaxes` able to give me this size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[load_img](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/ecb76f45887cc37a29f78fd5ded9c517aed9fd2d/keras_preprocessing/image/utils.py#L123) works with WH tuples. You are getting (28, 28, 1)(Width, Height, Channels). If you want to convert this into CWH format use [numpy.swapaxes](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.swapaxes.html).

```
import numpy as np

r = np.random.rand(3, 3, 1)
r_swapped = np.swapaxes(r, 0, 2)
print(r)
print(r.shape)
print(r_swapped)
print(r_swapped.shape)
```